# C - incompatible pointer to integer conversion?

Tags: c, integer, character, warnings

when I try to run the following code I get this warning:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to
  'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
    namesList[0]=name1;
```

Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    char namesList[20];
    char *name1="Nelson Mandela";
    namesList[0]=name1;
    return 0;
}
```

How do I get rid of this warning? Thank you.
Edit: Jonathan Leffler helped me fix it by doing `namesList[0] = *name1;`

Comment: Assign a char and not a char pointer.  For example, `namesList[0] = *names1;`.  Or change a variable definition. It depends on what you want to do

Comment: Do you want to assign a single character, or the whole string? Check out `strcpy` for the latter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you that worked :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you do:

```
char *name1="Nelson Mandela";
```

It's as if you did:

```
char * = const char *; // it's not the same type
```

I recommend doing the following for initialization:

```
char *name1= malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
strcpy(name1, "Nelson Mandela");
```

And maybe `namelist` should be in it, too?

```
char ** namelist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how you wrote your code, it seems that you want `namesList` to be an array of strings, so to fix it you should change your code to:

```
int main(){
    char *namesList[20];
    char *name1="Nelson Mandela";
    namesList[0]=name1;
    return 0;
}
```